# I can't see my app icon in my phone

Tags: android, icons, manifest

I use Android Studio
I build the app and play in device.

but, in device's normal display(like when phone open state),

I can't see the icon

In device Setting, I find the app in application manager,

but I can't see in normal display

this is my androidmanifest.xml

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/imagebutton_on"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".Activity.SplashActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:icon="@drawable/imagebutton_on"
            >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="roid.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
```

I embrassed of that

please help me

this is my full android-manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.thewell_dev.fourscompany">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/imagebutton_on"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".Activity.SplashActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:icon="@mipmap/imagebutton_on"
            >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="roid.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
                <data android:host="example.com"></data>
                <data android:scheme="http"></data>
                <data android:pathPattern="/.*"></data>

            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Activity.LoginActivity">


        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Activity.JoinActivity"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
            >

        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Activity.MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/ListTheme"
            android:icon="@mipmap/imagebutton_on"
            >



        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Activity.CompanyActivity"
            android:theme="@style/CompanyTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize"
            >

        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Activity.CardActivity"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
            >

        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Activity.CardListActivity"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
            >

        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Activity.CardPreviewActivity">


        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Activity.ManagementActivity">


        </activity>


        <activity android:name=".Activity.BeaconActivity">

        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Activity.CompanyCardActivity"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
            >

        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Activity.PreferencActivity"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
            >

        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Activity.FileListActivity">

        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Activity.PasswordChangeActivity"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
            >

        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Activity.RemoveUserActivity"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
            >

        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Activity.ProvisionActivity">

        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Activity.QuestionActivity">

        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Activity.ExpandActivity">

        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Activity.CardPrecaptureActivity"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
            >

        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Activity.BookMarkActivity"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
            >

        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Activity.FindPasswordActivity"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
            >

        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Activity.CardListDetailActivity">

        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Activity.UploadCertificationActivity">


        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Activity.UploadRewardActivity">


        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Activity.OnOffProductActivity"
            >

        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Activity.OnOffCompanyActivity"
            >

        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Do you actually have this typo in your manifest? `<category android:name="roid.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />` Fixing it should have an effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App Icon should be placed in `mipmap` folder. **Move** your `imagebutton_on` in `res\mipmap\` and **Replace** below code from `application` tag:

```
android:icon="@drawable/imagebutton_on">
```

**With:**

```
android:icon="@mipmap/imagebutton_on"
```

And resolve the following issue, as Markus Kauppinen mentioned:

```
<category android:name="roid.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

To:

```
 <category android:name="aroid.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Exactly where you can't see the app icon ? Your device's App drawer ?

Comment: Yes I can't see app Icon on that

Comment: What type of image are you using ? Is it png ? Did you set your app icon somewhere else ? Try uninstalling, then installing your app.

Comment: Exactly I can't change my icon on that, I can use ic_launcher either.
If I use another image, it will solve the problem i hope but it is not.
I use ic_launcher image nothing to do with
And I uninstall my app and reinstall but same

Comment: Can you please add your full manifest file to your question ?

Comment: You have a mistake on <category android:name="roid.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> . FIx this and your problem might be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try by removing following lines from all activity tags

```
android:icon="@mipmap/imagebutton_on"
```

Keep it in only application tag.